# What is the expected behavior when a RabbitMQ durable queue runs out of RAM?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, task-queue

My understanding of RabbitMQ durable queues (i.e. delivery_mode = 2) is that they run in RAM, but that messages are flushed to disk so that they can be recovered in the event that the process is restarted or the machine is rebooted.

It's unclear to me though what the expected behavior is when the machine runs out of memory. If the queue gets overloaded, dies, and needs to be restored, then simply loading the messages from the disk-backed store would consume all available RAM.

Do durable queues only load a subset of the messages into RAM in this scenario?

Comment: You're mistaking durable queues and persistent messages. delivery_mode = 2 makes a message persistent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5047012/286655

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ will page the messages to disc as memory fills up. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html section "Configuring the Paging Threshold".