# acks_late not recovering scheduled tasks after Rabbitmq crash

Tags: php, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery with https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php for PHP. Reliability is important for our project. So I want to be sure that all tasks that scheduled are executed even Rabbitmq crash. So I scheduled one task, then I stopped Rabbitmq and started again. When scheduled time come, task not executed. 
Here is my task.

```
from celery import Celery
import subprocess

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task(acks_late=True)
def hipoCheckSubscriptions(args):
    return subprocess.call(['php54','/path/to/script', '--args='+args])
```

Please help, what I am doing wrong? And is there any recipes for my case.

Comment: Check if the queue Celery creates is persistent/durable. If not, look for the appropriate Celery setting. See $persistent_messages in Celery-PHP constructor. Also, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046944/why-is-rabbitmq-not-persisting-messages-on-a-durable-queue

Comment: @gdr Yes, you are right about **celery-php** **$persistent_messages** option. But I used Yii extenstion called **celery-yii** for my web app. They missed this option in settings or I couldn't find it. So I override  **celery-yii** to make messages durable. My solution is down below.

Comment: Makes sense. If you're actively using celery-yii, please consider contributing some work to that project - they're separate from celery-php and it looks like they're a little behind on features.

Comment: @gdr I wrote an issue to celery-yii project on their GitHub page https://github.com/ecesena/celery-yii/issues/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an Yii extension called celery-yii, for my web app. I didn't found any message durability settings in default configuration of the extension. So I searched all extension classes to find which method is responsible for posting messages to celery. I found that is **celery::PostTask** method. In **$params** array it passes message publication settings to the celery exchange. So I added one more option **delivery_mode=2** for message durability. And this message is survived after RabbbitMQ crash. So I have solved my problems this way.